# Git hash as RAILS_ASSET_ID. Where to cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use the git hash of files as asset id.
For that I created an initializer like below.

```
require 'grit'
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module AssetTagHelper
      def rewrite_asset_path(source)
        asset_id = rails_asset_id(source)
        if asset_id.blank?
          source
        else
          "/s/#{asset_id}" + source
        end
      end

        def rails_asset_id(source)
          repo = Grit::Repo.new('.')
          ENV["RAILS_ASSET_ID"] || 
            repo.log('master', "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/#{source}", :max_count => 1).first.id_abbrev rescue ""
        end
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine but I want to cache the hash for the files somewhere. I could use an instance variable but I am not sure if those are cleaned per requests. Where can I put that so it persists after the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class variable seems to be the best way to do this.